# How to preserve leading 0 digits from an integer or varchar in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, qsqlquery

My purpose is to add +1 so that the desired value became 001 + 1 == 002 but it returns me 2 instead of 002
Please see the below sample query

```
DECLARE @l_EmploymentID NVARCHAR(30)/ int
SELECT @l_EmploymentID = 001
SELECT LEN(@l_EmploymentID)-- output is 1
```

If I get the length as 3 then I can get the desired value 002 using REPLICATE function
Please suggest me how can I get length as 3 or summing 1 with 001 = 002

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to pad it after with `right ('000' +<your result>)`

Comment: The amount 001 is a dynamic number. How do I count leading 0 numbers? @Andrew

Comment: If you want a numeric value, use a numeric type. If you want a string value, use strings everywhere and don't treat them as numbers. It's that simple. In your second statement, you use a NUMERIC literal for the assignment. You will see this flaw if you examine (by selecting or printing) the variable immediately after assignment. But this smells like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the number of proceeding zeros by calculating the difference in the number of characters of the original string by the number of characters after converting the original string to an INT. This difference can then be used in your REPLICATE function to prepare the prefix for your result.

```
DECLARE @l_EmploymentID varchar(30)
SELECT @l_EmploymentID = '001'
SELECT REPLICATE('0', LEN(@l_EmploymentID) - LEN(CAST(@l_EmploymentID AS INT))) + CAST(@l_EmploymentID + 1 as VARCHAR) --output is 002
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a string, you need single quotes:

```
SELECT @l_EmploymentID = '001'
```

Otherwise, the value is interpreted as the integer `1`.

If you want to output an integer with leading zeros, then `FORMAT()` can help:

```
SELECT FORMAT(1, '000')
```

Comment: The amount 001 is a dynamic number. It may be 00001 also. How do I count leading 0 numbers? That;s the problem.

Comment: @GopalBiswas . . . You use single quotes to turn it into a string.  That is what this answer specifies.